# C Directly/Explicit passing parameters

Tags: c, pointers

If I call a function in C and pass in a struct (not by pointers nor references for those c++ readers), it copies the object. If I pass in a struct with an array in it, it copies the array (as stated by professor in class). But what happens if I pass in a struct that contains a circular reference back to the object. How does it copy the whole struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It copies the struct, and the pointer inside the copied struct contains the address of the original object.

Comment: Can you please expand on that?

Comment: Not sure how to best expand.  If the original struct contains a pointer (there are no "references" in C), the pointer in the copy of the struct will have the same value as the original.  If the original pointer had a valid address, the copy will have the same address.  If the original pointer was uninitialized, the copy will have the same uninitialized value.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have a reference back to the same `struct` is by adding a pointer to the `struct` that points back. This pointer is copied in the same way as the rest of the `struct`.